# Flushing navigation top, left, and right without content div colliding

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Golden Gators</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <nav id='navContainer'>
                <h1 id='navHeader'>Golden Gators</h1>
            </nav>
            <div id='contentContainer'>
                asd
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my problem is why does it do that? I tried everything including 'display: block', not using 'position: absolute' (Which worked but i don't know how to flush it without this), and even 'position: fixed' (Same thing as absolute).

Can anyone tell me why it does that? I do know that 'absolute' destroys your document NORMAL flow but I thought it would still respond to display: blocks? Why is it not listening?

EXTRA:
If possible could anyone link me to any good html and css positioning tutorials? I've done about a good 100+ queries of search on google and could not find any that explains the 'deep core' of how css works.

---

ANSWER:
Why does this work?

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Clash;
    src: url(supercell.ttf);
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navContainer {
    background-color: #3a5795;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#contentContainer {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#navHeader {
    font-family: Clash;
    color: #ffd700;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Golden Gators</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <nav id='navContainer'>
                <h1 id='navHeader'>Golden Gators</h1>
            </nav>
            <div id='contentContainer'>
                asd
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem with this:
Whenever I try to put a navigation bar it makes the entire container enlarge which I do not like.

Question for this:
When I type 'float: left' it expands up top and bottom doing the effect I want it to. Which is a bit odd to me as I thought `float: left` only moves to the left. Why does it expand up when I do float: left? And this just emphasizes the fact that I do not understand 'css' at it's 'deepest'.

Answer (score 1):

I did not completely understand what you were asking (probably because it's pretty late) but I played around with your code a bit. Here is what I can tell you (if I'm wrong hopefully someone will correct me):

1. Browsers have default values for elements. The reason your  container gets larger when you use float: left is because it is moved outside of the document flow. The default padding and margin value on the h1 element are what enlarges the container. (Notice that the asd outside of the nav container doesn't seem to move. This is because of the margin on the h1 element.)
2. The same explanation goes to why your nav container grows when you try to put a navigation bar into the container. If you are trying to make a horizontal navigation bar, try using display: inline-block on the h1, ul, and li elements. This will make them readable from left to right. (Hopefully this is what you were trying to do.)
3. As for web tutorials. Try the following:
   w3schools  --> A great website for learning about web development.

Treehouse Web Tutorials --> Sign up for their free 14 trial and go into their front-end web track. you will learn ALOT.

I'd like to apologize if I gave a pretty bad response. Hopefully this could be of help to you in some way!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will definitely take a look at those sites that are listed.